# Count all member messages on server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I need to count all user messages they sent on server, even before bot was added, is this possible and how? I googled it a lot but found no answers

Comment: There are no answers because a bot cannot access messages when it wasn't present in the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You cannot request the amount of messages sent in any way meaning you won't be able to access the messages sent before your bot joined at all. For messages sent after you can just increment an `integer` in the `client.on('messageCreated', () => {})` listener.

If you really need the amount and you are savvy with python you may be able to create a separate program that opens discord, searches for messages sent by a specific user in the top right search bar, and returns the search results amount, but this would be a lot of work for something that seems inconsequential.